# go 1d array combine 2d array with append

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array

I have two one dimensional array and I want to combine the two single arrays into one multi dimensional array with **append**.

How would this be done for the fastest in go?

```
val time []int64
val value []float64

val 2darray [][]int64, float64
```

Would append be the best way to do this in go?

Comment: `val 2darray [][]int64, float64` <- what does this mean?

Comment: hello there, welcome to Stack Overflow and welcome to Go golang.org I think you should take the golang tour tour.golang.org

Comment: [][] int64 float64 are the 2 columns of time and value

Comment: It shouldn't be `val`but `var`.

Comment: Even after changing `val` to `var`, you have invalid syntax:
`var 2darray [][]int64, float64` is not valid Go.

Comment: It's not clear how you want the resulting slice should look. Could you provide an example, perhaps in another language?

Comment: looking for the best way to take 2 1D arrays or slices how ever you want to call or refer to them and combine both 1D into 2D.  So you have 2D with col1 and col2 time and value

Comment: Create a structure that has 2 fields: time and value and create an array of those structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how it can be done:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TimeAndValue struct {
    time  int64
    value float64
}

func main() {
    times := []int64{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    values := []float64{1.23, 2.34, 3.45, 4.56, 5.67}

    timesAndValues := zip(times, values)

    fmt.Println(timesAndValues)
}

func zip(ts []int64, vs []float64) []TimeAndValue {
    if len(ts) != len(vs) {
        panic("not same length")
    }

    var res []TimeAndValue
    for i, t := range ts {
        res = append(res, TimeAndValue{time: t, value: vs[i]})
    }

    return res
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1OWJ1HG1XL

Comment: What I am looking for!  Thank!